# Java update sql Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have problem with update sql command in java, I am using jdbc to connect to mysql database. When I want do this:

```
db.CreatePreparedStatement("UPDATE kontakty SET Telefon = ?,Mobil = ?,Email = ? WHERE `idKontakty` = ?");
db.SetInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldTelefon.getText()));
db.SetInt(2, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldMobil.getText()));
db.SetString(3, jTextFieldEmail.getText());
db.SetInt(4, 1);
```

It shows this error.

```
    Srp 20, 2017 8:10:42 ODP. autoservis.SpravaZamestnancu.SpravaZamestnancu updateKontakt
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3327)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3312)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3351)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3302)
    at autoservis.DatovaVrstva.Databaze.SetInt(Databaze.java:69)
    at autoservis.SpravaZamestnancu.SpravaZamestnancu.updateKontakt(SpravaZamestnancu.java:682)
    at autoservis.SpravaZamestnancu.SpravaZamestnancu.jButtonUpravitActionPerformed(SpravaZamestnancu.java:361)
    at autoservis.SpravaZamestnancu.SpravaZamestnancu.access$200(SpravaZamestnancu.java:23)
    at autoservis.SpravaZamestnancu.SpravaZamestnancu$3.actionPerformed(SpravaZamestnancu.java:123)
    at ...
```

I have 4 "?" and 4 Set function. But this don't work.

This is class Databaze.

```
package autoservis.DatovaVrstva;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Savepoint;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Databaze {

    private static Databaze instance;
    private final String pripojovaciRetezec = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Autoservis";
    private final String uzivatelDB= "pripojenikDB";
    private final String hesloDB = "pripojenikDB";
    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;
    private String query;
    private Savepoint savePoint;
    private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    private Databaze() {
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(pripojovaciRetezec, uzivatelDB, hesloDB);
            if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Databaze.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Databaze GetInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Databaze();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Statement CreateStatement() throws SQLException {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        return statement;
    }

    public PreparedStatement CreatePreparedStatement(String query) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        return preparedStatement;
    }
    public void SetString(int pozice, String hodnota) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setString(pozice, hodnota);
    }
    public void SetInt(int pozice, int hodnota) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setInt(pozice, hodnota);
    }
    public void SetDate(int pozice, Date hodnota) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setDate(pozice, hodnota);
    }
    public void SetNull(int pozice,int typ) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setNull(pozice, typ);
    }
    public void SetDouble(int pozice, double hodnota) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setDouble(pozice, hodnota);
    }
    public ResultSet ExecuteQuery(String query) throws SQLException{
        return statement.executeQuery(query);
    }
    public boolean Execute(String query) throws SQLException{
        return statement.execute(query);
    }
    public int ExecuteUpdate(String query) throws SQLException{
        return statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    public ResultSet ExecutePreparedQuery() throws SQLException{
        return preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    }
    public boolean ExecutePrepared() throws SQLException{
        return preparedStatement.execute();
    }
    public int ExecutePreparedUpdate() throws SQLException{
        return preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
    public boolean IsClosed() throws SQLException{
        return connection.isClosed();
    }
    public void Close() throws SQLException{
        connection.close();
    }
    public void Commit() throws SQLException{
        connection.commit();
    }
    public void SetAutoCommit(boolean commit) throws SQLException{
        connection.setAutoCommit(commit);
    }
    public void RollBack() throws SQLException{
        connection.rollback(savePoint);
    }
    public void SetSavePoint() throws SQLException{
        savePoint = connection.setSavepoint();
    }
}
```

Comment: @YCF_L I was under the impression they are just backed by an array, is the -1 done implicitly? Okay, thank you for the link, learned something.

Comment: Are you sure that your compiled code is updated with what you show there? As a side note, why  do you use back ticks for  `idKontakty` ?

Comment: What API/library do you use? JDBC does not contain `CreatePreparedStatement()` method; and the naming convention is not Java-like. Do you show us a real code or a pseudo-code?

Comment: @Roman Puchkovskiy i am using own class with name Databaze and in this form i have private static Databaze db and db = Databaze.GetInstance(); in class Databaze i have connection string and username with password a and metods like public PreparedStatement CreatePreparedStatement(String query) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        return preparedStatement;
    }

Comment: @newim123 Ok, then please show us the code of your `Databaze` class so we could know what happens between the code you already shown and JDBC API.

Comment: @ Roman Puchkovskiy in edit thanks

Comment: Is that class used from many different threads? What you have there is essentially a stateful singleton holding DB resources (statements and the connection). That's a bad idea. Connections should come from a proper connection pool implementation and statements should be scoped within the method that uses the statement so that they are as short-lived as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't using the correct [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) you are using another API.

**Why?**

because

1. there should be a method `prepareStatement` and not `CreatePreparedStatement`
2. there should be a method `setInt` with lowercase `s` and not `SetInt` with uppercase `S`

For this reason, I assume you are using another thing and not the correct `PreparedStatement`

So to solve your problem you can use:

```
Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);

PreparedStatement ps = db.prepareStatement("UPDATE kontakty SET Telefon = ?, Mobil = ?, Email = ? WHERE `idKontakty` = ?");

ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldTelefon.getText()));
ps.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldMobil.getText()));
ps.setString(3, jTextFieldEmail.getText());
ps.setInt(4, 1);
```

---

**Edit**

How to explain this, your design is a little complicated, ok.

When you call `public PreparedStatement CreatePreparedStatement(String query)` you pass your query in it, so it create a prepared statement with this query and **return it** which mean you have to put it in another variable `PreparedStatement` like this :

```
PreparedStatement pst = db.CreatePreparedStatement(
        "UPDATE kontakty SET Telefon = ?, Mobil = ?, Email = ? WHERE `idKontakty` = ?");
```

Then you call the setters (*there is a specific syntax of setters and getters, one of them should not start with upper letter*), which set the parameters in the static Prepared Statement :

```
private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
```

In this case you **can** get `NullPointException` because the `PreparedStatement` is null, in your case you don't because you already call `CreatePreparedStatement`.
So you note that you don't set the attribute in the correct statement for that you get this error, instead you have to use it like this :

```
PreparedStatement pst = db.CreatePreparedStatement(
            "UPDATE kontakty SET Telefon = ?, Mobil = ?, Email = ? WHERE `idKontakty` = ?");

pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldTelefon.getText()));
pst.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldMobil.getText()));
pst.setString(3, jTextFieldEmail.getText());
pst.setInt(4, 1);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

No need to call `SetInt(..)`, ...

Hope you understand your problem now.

**Note**

please do not use upper letters in the first letter of your methods, this not good practice.

Comment: i have class Databaze and in this class i have one instance of connect to db.  and metods like this public PreparedStatement CreatePreparedStatement(String query) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        return preparedStatement;
    }
    public void SetString(int pozice, String hodnota) throws SQLException{
        preparedStatement.setString(pozice, hodnota);
    }

Comment: then you have to share the full code please @newim123

Comment: Note that the underlying problem is probably one of concurrent access, where another thread has used the same (or different) instance of `Databaze` and set another statement in the static field.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel yes i agree, also i think the OP make a complicated design for that he/she doesn't understand what happened exactly